# Using SCP and nohup to transfer large folder between servers

Tags: ssh, scp, nohup

I want to copy a ~50GB folder from one server to another. This is understandably going to take quite a while, so I'd like to be able to perform it "in the background". Using the standard SCP command requires me to keep the console open. I read up about `nohup`, which seems like it should do the trick, but I'm struggling to get it to work. Even this seems to require the console to be left open - after typing in the command, the `nohup` program remains open, and if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit it then the transfer stops. Am I misunderstanding what `nohup` does? Or how else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think would be easier to start the `scp` from a `screen` session, and once it's copying detach from the `screen`, any time you can go back to that screen session and check how is it going.

```
screen
scp foo bar
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from screen

Then reattach to screen:

```
screen -x
```

Answer (score 0):

The name `nohup` refers to the `HUP` signal, which was traditionally sent to processes when the (telephone-)line a terminal was connected through to a server was hung up. `nohup` prevents that signal from being sent, even when "hanging up" nowadays just means "closing the terminal window".

tl;dr
you want to just close the terminal window (or kill the ssh connection on your side) instead of logging out of the server regularly. `nohup` will keep your process running, even if the terminal connection breaks in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are few problems:

1. If you want to run the command in the background, you need to append `&` to the command. Something like `nohup scp file server:path/ &`. It will run in background and if you will close the console, it will still transfer the file.
2. Use `sftp` instead of `scp`. It gives much better performance results (especially for such large files). SCP is very slow. Even `sftp` supports batch mode: `sftp -b <(echo "cd path"; echo "put file") server &`